# C# run process microsip.exe without access to system micro

Tags: c#, sip

I run microsip.exe from my application as

> Process.Start("D:\Downloads\MicroSIP-3.21.3\microsip.exe",
> "06600100010099908");

It works and run calls, but call cant get an access to system microphone. What i should do?

What I have tried: run as "runas" and set 
in manifest

```
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

if i run microSip from desktop it works well!